# How do I set the generic parameter to only specific type parameters in this Windsor installer using the fluent API?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I currently have this installer:

```
class DemiInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, 
        IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(ServicePlan),
            typeof(AccountGetService),
            typeof(ServiceOrder),
            typeof(WorkRosterHistory),
            typeof(WorkRoster),
            typeof(SmallHoursAmount),
            typeof(Nurse),
            typeof(ServicePlanHistory),
            typeof(ServicePlanLine),
            typeof(ServicePlanLineHistory),
            typeof(AccountGetServiceAbsence),
            typeof(NurseAbsence),
            typeof(Holiday)
        };

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component
                .For(typeof(IRepository<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(type))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(ARRepository<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(type)));
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of iterating over the list is there a function in the Windsor's Fluent API that implements this kind of behaviour?
Can I do other kinds of filtering based on the generic type?

Comment: why? What's the actual scenario? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: I am trying to register only some of the types of the repositories because I don't need all of them.

Comment: @the_drow: what happens if you *do* register all of them? it will be significantly easier and it won't do any harm.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: I am running something that must initialized as fast as possible but I have services that I need to resolve.

Comment: @the_drow: how many repositories would it register so that it makes a significant impact on performance? How long does it really take? Have you measured?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: Of course I did, I have 60 repositories, I need only 14. Resolving with 60 repositories takes 13 seconds, resolving 14 takes 06-0.8 seconds.

Comment: @the_drow: did you mean 'registering' instead of 'resolving'? 13 seconds is too much for 60 components, something else is wrong there.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: No, I meant resolving the dependencies with 60 repositories registered takes 13 seconds.

Comment: @the_drow: there seems to be something wrong with your components... there's no way resolving with 60 components in the container can take 13 seconds. Some dependency is probably taking too long to initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(ARRepository<>)));
```

Comment: Did that, it registers all ARRepsitories in the assembly. I need only some.

Comment: @the_drow: this does *not* explicitly register all repositories individually, it registers the open generic service. It's different from roelofb's solution.

Comment: So this allows me to resolve only what I need right? Could you explain roelofb's solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
                            .WithService.FromInterface());
```

Comment: Why aren't you using ImplementedBy()? How will it know to resolve into ARRepository? How can I not include in the container everything that doesn't have a generic type parameter of Foo, Bar, Baz...?